# Deleting a property on an object in the right way

Tags: javascript

```
var actual = { first: 1, second : 2 }
var copy = actual;

delete copy.first;
```

When I console log the copy, it doesnt have the first property on it, but when I console log actual, even that object doesnt have the first property.

Can someone please explain what is happening here? And how to avoid this?

Expected:

```
actual: { first: 1, second : 2 }
Copy: { second: 2 }
```

P.S: I know that that I can assign second property directly on the copy object without copying, this is just an example. I'm dealing with very large objects. So I have to copy and then delete the properties without affecting the actual object.

Thank you

Comment: `copy === actual`, it is not a copy, it holds a reference to the same exact object. You may want to use `Object.assign`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`, or as suggested by @elclanrs, `Object.assign()`

```
var actual = { first: 1, second : 2 }
var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(actual));
delete copy.first;
```

```
var actual = { first: 1, second : 2 }
var copy = Object.assign({}, actual);
delete copy.first;
```

Comment: See also [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make a copy of the object but just copied the reference.
If you want to copy an object, consider using ES6 `Object.assign` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) or lodash's `assign` ([link](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)).

`Object.assign` takes objects as arguments. All properties of objects are copied to first object in argument list and reference to the first object is returned.

```
var actual = { first: 1, second : 2 };
var copy = Object.assign({}, actual);

delete copy.first;
```